# Getting a concrete element from an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

This seems easy but after two hours my head hurts.

I have a categoryIndex (from a select) and I want to get the category from an observableArray who have that Id.

How I do that? I tried with indexOf (but Im not sure how it works and I looked the doc of course), I tried linq.js but the Where is hard to use or Im stupid (I don't know how to get the Id from a category and compare it).

My observableArray is this:

```
categories[category { Id=2,  Name="Pink", ...}, category { Id=1,  Name="Green",  ...}]
```

So, I just need one way to get the "Pink" category if my Index is 2.

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
viewModel.addNote = function() {
    var selectedCategoryIndex = $("#Categories").val();
    var selectedCategory = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.categories(), function(item) {
        return item.Id === selectedCategoryIndex;
    });

}.bind(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I usually use a KO utility function `ko.utils.arrayFirst` to do this type of thing.  It just loops through an array and returns the first item that matches the predicate passed to it.

You would use it like this:

```
selectedId = 2;

var category = ko.utils.arrayFirst(categories(), function(category) {
   return category.Id === selectedId;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the number one. But I'm getting null. I edited with the code. selectedCategoryIndex is ok, it have the right Id but selectedCategory seems to be null. Btw, why firebug doesn't work right with knockout? it always says that this.categories() is empty but if I assign that to a new var, firebug can see the data in the new var but not in the observableArray.

Comment: My guess is that item.Id is 2 and $("#Categories").val() is "2".  You can do a parseInt on the result or use == instead of ===.  Is there a reason why you are reading the val() of an element rather than having that value tracked in your view model?

Comment: Ouch, JS 1, me 0. Im a desktop dev trying to learn some web dev too. I had bad experiences with html helpers (ASP.NET MVC) and knockout so that's why Im not using knockout to track my DropDownList. Thanks again.